# How can I insert minute:seconds format time interval to postgresql in right way?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I need to enter the time into the database in the format minutes:seconds.
I have created the table as follows:

```
'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS players (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, DATE DATE NOT NULL, NAME varchar(32), TIME_ON_ICE interval)
```

I enter the information into the database as follows:

```
sql_string = """ INSERT INTO players (DATE, NAME, TIME_ON_ICE) VALUES (%s,%s,%s) """
```

The output is as follows:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM players ORDER BY TIME_ON_ICE DESC ")
[(177,
  datetime.date(2022, 1, 16),
  'Morgan Rielly',
  datetime.timedelta(days=1, seconds=13260)),
 (201,
  datetime.date(2022, 1, 18),
  'Roman Josi',
  datetime.timedelta(days=1, seconds=13080)),
 (250,
  datetime.date(2022, 1, 29),
  'Neal Pionk',
  datetime.timedelta(days=1, seconds=7860))]
```

How do I get the minutes and seconds in the output? And how do I correctly enter the minutes and seconds in the table in my case?

Comment: SELECT CAST('27 minutes 41 seconds' AS INTERVAL);

Comment: May be save seconds count and convert into  27:41 format when selecting as, like: `SELECT TO_CHAR('1661 second'::interval, 'MI:SS');`

Comment: @OtoShavadze, I don't completely get when should I use your approach? I should use it when I retrieve information? I mean, when I do "SELECT * FROM players ORDER BY TIME_ON_ICE DESC " ? Sorry, I am new in SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You can save total time as seconds quantity in INT column and convert in minute:second format when retrieving data, something like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS players (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    DATE DATE NOT NULL, 
    NAME varchar(32), 
    TIME_ON_ICE INT
);


INSERT INTO players (DATE, NAME, TIME_ON_ICE) 
VALUES 
('2000-01-01', 'Morgan Rielly', 1661) , 
('2000-01-01', 'Roman Josi', 1289) , 
('2000-01-01', 'Neal Pionk', 774);


SELECT 
ID, DATE, NAME, TIME_ON_ICE, 
TO_CHAR((TIME_ON_ICE||'second')::interval, 'MI:SS') AS minute_second
FROM players ORDER BY TIME_ON_ICE DESC;
```

Comment: It works for me, thanks. 
Can you give a short explanation how "((TIME_ON_ICE||'second')::interval, 'MI:SS') AS minute_second" works.  I've found some examples for TO_CHAR function but there another syntax (TO_CHAR(expression, format))

Answer (score 1):

if you want to convert your timedelta to minutes and seconds, do like this :

```
import datetime

duration = datetime.timedelta(days = 1, seconds=13080)
totalsecondes = duration.total_seconds()
hours = totalsecondes //3600
minutes = (totalsecondes %3600) // 60
secondes =(totalsecondes %3600)%60
print ("%d:%d" %(minutes ,secondes))
```